# Is there a way to solve a linear system of equations using Google Sheets, with a non-square matrix?

Tags: matrix, google-sheets, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to create a tool for our business that estimates labor hours required by task. I have historical data of the number of tasks completed by day and the total labor hours on that day. I only have knowledge of using Ax = b

A values are the quantity of a specific task on a day;
b values are the total number of labor hours;
x values would be the # hours to complete the task

[Here is a link to my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qhHg8eemdveXRw3OhqiyDfQ7mcvsbkrUqOYAATkIOMg/edit?usp=sharing)

As you can see on the tab "Daily Log," there are 5 days of data and 6 tasks we are measuring. The contents of Column B indicate we washed 15 cars, changed one light, wiper, tire, brake pad and oil filter. This took 3 hours to complete all of this work.

I have successfully converted this to a square matrix by multiplying the transposed array with the original array, as shown on the "Square Matrix" tab, using the following formula:

```
=MMULT(arrayformula(OFFSET('Daily Log'!$B$4,0,0,COUNTA('Daily Log'!$A:$A)-3,COUNTA('Daily Log'!$1:$1)-1)),arrayformula(OFFSET(Transpose!$D$2,0,0,COUNTA(Transpose!$A:$A)-1,COUNTA(Transpose!$1:$1)-3)))
```

The purpose of using OFFSET in the formula is so that as new data is entered on the Daily Log (either a new date of data [which would add a column], or a new task is measured [which would add a row]), the matrices will adjust their size to capture all data (which would not be done if using a fixed range).

Now, when I try to take the inverse of my square matrix, I get a #NUM! error if the 'Daily Log' is not size m x m. This is limiting, as I would only be able to measure the same number of tasks as I have number of days recorded. With the example displayed on the sheet linked above, I am trying to measure 6 tasks over the course of 5 days, resulting in the #NUM! error on the "Inverse Matrix" tab. If I remove the sixth task, the inverse matrix works beautifully!

**I am very open to a different approach if it's best I scrap this altogether. Ultimately, as long as I can somehow estimate the amount of time it takes to complete each task based on aggregated historical data (i.e. I only know the total # hours for the day, not how long each task took), then my mission will be accomplished.**

Thank you in advance for your time & help.

Edit:

I am not sure what the solution should be mathematically yet. I was planning get the inverse matrix at least displaying properly before I confirm the accuracy of the results.

Maybe if I try reframing my desired result it would be helpful, because honestly I'm not even sure I'm using the correct mathematical application:

Each day of data will represent its own problem:

Az + By + Cx + = θ, where

[CAPS]-an integer representing the coefficient, known. It's the number of times a task was performed.

[lower]-the unknown

[θ]-the total duration of time, known.

My hope is to compare the results of each of the days' data to find increasingly more confident estimates for what the unknowns are. To me, the unknowns represent hours per task.

Comment: So the expected output is 6x5 matrix (1 estimation per task per day)?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz thank you for your response. I have updated my original post with an edit all the way down at the bottom, since my reply was a bit lengthy.

Comment: Oh, I see. I really don't think a linear system is what you want to do, though I get how you might think so. The issue is that a solution to a linear system has to be consistent, meaning only one solution can exist, but you want to do an estimation. IMO, the best and simplest thing you can do with the information you have is just do something with the average of each task across all days and the average number of labor hours. Then you can use `AVEDEV`/`STDEV` for each task to get a sense on how uniform/reliable your estimation is (Lower=better).

Comment: Ok, thank you for directing me towards a more useable approach!